# How can I wrap text in a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone7 development and have a little issue.

I have a textblock(Label) in my interface, and in runtime I use that label to display dyanamic data. The problem is when the text is too long(than the width of the screen), it only displays half of the data(Only the content that fits the width). It doesn't matter to go for multiple lines, but I want to display the full content. I tested with Textblock(Label) properties, but didn't find any working.

Can someone please help me. (I am Using visual studio 2010) . Thanks

---

Following is the XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="98">
    <Ellipse Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Margin="6,13,0,0" Fill="#FFDB4C4C" />
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,10,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="402" AllowDrop="False" TextWrapping="NoWrap" UseLayoutRounding="True" DataContext="{Binding}" />
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,44,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="402" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting the property `TextWrapping = "Wrap"` might solve your problem as long as there is enough vertical space.

**EDIT**

Depending on how you would like the resize behavior this should work:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Margin="5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#FFDB4C4C" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Name="textBlock1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" UseLayoutRounding="True" Grid.Column="1" Text="sdfsdf sdf sdf sdf sd f sdf" />
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Name="textBlock2" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="sdfsdf sdf sdf sdf sd f sdf" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Erno, I tried with that property. It didn't work. Again I tested when I saw your post. No it just wrap the content that fits to the screen width. It still doesn't display the entire content

Comment: Please post the xaml and perhaps a a screenshot of what happens and what should happen. I am not quite sure I understand you.

Comment: Yes It works. Iam sorry. Have to increase the height of the TextBlock. Is there any way it Automatically get the correct height. because We are not sure the data enough to 2 line 3 lines or how many.

Comment: Show the xaml! If you put the textblock in a container that stretches its content (Grid) or scrolls its content (ScrollViewer) you should be fine.

Comment: You added specific margins to the textblocks, that is why they do not resize.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to write it without specific margins. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, It worked with Height=Auto... Thank you very much for your time and Help

Comment: I added an example to my answer.